# Add a button on right view of UItextfield in such way that, text should not overlap the button

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield

I can add a button to a textfield on the right hand side of the UITextField using the right view however, the text overlaps on the button. Below is the code for right view button

```
        UIView.commitAnimations()
        var btnColor = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        btnColor.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openEmoji), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
        btnColor.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(textField.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
        btnColor.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "send.png"), forState: .Normal)
        textField.addSubview(btnColor)
```

Please let me know how to give padding from right view for text.

Comment: Handy tip. If you make the `rightView` an image, rather than a button. And add gesture recognizers as you see fit.  Don't forget to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = true` !!

Answer (score 85, accepted):

use the **rightView** property of the UITextField. Basically, there are two properties (this one and leftView accordingly) that allow you to place custom views/controls inside the UITextField. You can control whether those views are shown or not by means of **rightViewMode/leftViewMode** properties:

```
textField.rightView = btnColor
textField.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
```

for e.g

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "send.png"), for: .normal)
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -16, 0, 0)
button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(txt.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refresh), for: .touchUpInside)
textField.rightView = button
textField.rightViewMode = .always
```

and call the action as

```
@IBAction func refresh(_ sender: Any) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks All.. Its working now. I will accept the answer. Can Any one tell me how to give a space after image from left hand view for the text?

Comment: @Saty - not like its is depent upon user based

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik As there is an image in left view so I want to have some space after the image so there must be some gap between leftview image and text

Comment: @Saty - yes absolutly, use leftview concept

Comment: @Saty - any other queries

Comment: when I declare 'IBAction', it shows me error - "Only Instance method can be declared @IBAction"

Comment: @Tejas - You need to put the function inside the UIViewController not outside

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : Thanks for quick response. I understand your point. But, I am configuring this button inside a custom cell class 'UITableViewCell'. where I have all outlets of my text field. And, based on Bool value, I make it editable or non-editable. When editable, I need to show a dropdown on click of this button.

Comment: @Tejas - ok what the issue u faced

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik any suggestion or solution for that?

Comment: Same: "Only Instance method can be declared @IBAction"

Comment: @Anbu.karthik the text from the text box goes behind the image if you type for long enough, how do you prevent this?

Comment: @CraigP you can inherit UITextField, and override `editingRect` so you have padding on right size. `let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 32) return bounds.inset(by: padding)`

Comment: Working for me.....

Answer (score 9):

Create UITextField extension and add below method in it and you can change UIButton code as per your requirement.

```
func setRightViewIcon(icon: UIImage) {
    let btnView = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: ((self.frame.height) * 0.70), height: ((self.frame.height) * 0.70)))
    btnView.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
    btnView.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 3)
    self.rightViewMode = .always
    self.rightView = btnView
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Correct answer Swift3+**

If you just override the methods, the text may overlap the right view. This code completely solves this problem.

You UITextField subclass:

```
//...

private func setInsets(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    var totalInsets = insets //property in you subClass

    if let leftView = leftView  { totalInsets.left += leftView.frame.origin.x }
    if let rightView = rightView { totalInsets.right += rightView.bounds.size.width }

    return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, totalInsets)
}

override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return setInsets(forBounds: bounds)
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return setInsets(forBounds: bounds)
}

override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    return setInsets(forBounds: bounds)
}

override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    var rect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.origin.x -= insets.right

    return rect
}

override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    var rect = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
    rect.origin.x += insets.left

    return rect
}
```

Comment: how to get insets from subclass

Answer (score 2):

you can assign button at  right view of textfield

```
var btnColor = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            btnColor.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.openEmoji), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            btnColor.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(textField.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
            btnColor.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "send.png"), forState: .Normal)
            textField.rightView = btnColor
```

Answer (score 2):

```
internal var btnDropDown: UIButton {
    let size: CGFloat = 25.0
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DropDownImage"), for: .normal)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -(size/2.0), 0, 0)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width - size, y: 0.0, width: size, height: size)
    return button
}
```

**And I used it like this**:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()   
    textField.rightView = self.btnDropDown
    textField.rightViewMode = .always
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve same as shown below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var textFieldBtn: UIButton {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "image.png"), for: .normal)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(textField.frame.size.width - 40), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(40), height: CGFloat(30))
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshContent), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}

func refreshContent() {

    // Add your code here to handle button.
}
```

Add to textField.

```
textField.rightView = textFieldBtn
textField.rightViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift4**

```
func setupUI() {
   let imgSearch = UIImageView();
   let imgSearch = UIImage(named: "search");

   // set frame on image before adding it to the uitextfield
   imgSearch.image = imagePassword;
   imgSearch.frame = CGRect(x: txtSearchField.frame.size.width - 40 , y: 5, width: 22, height: 22)
   txtSearchField.rightView = imgSearch
   txtSearchField.rightViewMode = .always
}
```

**Call function like this**

```
 // MARK: View lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupUI()
    }
```