# image icon not shown in right side of text box in swift

Tags: ios, swift

1. image in the right side of text box, but image padding not correct:

   ```
   let imageView = UIImageView();
   let imageDown = UIImage(named: "down-arrow.png");
   imageView.image = imageDown;
   imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight)
   pickerSelect.rightViewMode = .always
    pickerSelect.rightView = imageView
   ```

   2. their is no padding from right in textbox. 
      How to set padding of image .

Comment: why are you adding paddingview?

Comment: check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082339/add-a-button-on-right-view-of-uitextfield-in-such-way-that-text-should-not-over/42082369#42082369

Comment: `imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight)` x = 5?

Comment: is `pickerSelect` is `IBoutlet` or you have created it programatically?

Comment: @MahendraGP yes its textbook

Comment: I have changed my code, please check @MeenorRanpura

Comment: Do you use RTL ?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple :

```
txtField.rightViewMode = .always
txtField.rightView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "down-arrow.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to make custome textfield

```
@IBDesignable
class RDTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var leftImage:UIImage?{
        didSet{
            if let image = leftImage{
                self.leftViewMode = .always
                let image = UIImageView.init(image: image)
                image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.leftView = image
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var RightImage:UIImage?{
        didSet{
            if let image = RightImage{
                self.rightViewMode = .always
                let image = UIImageView.init(image: image)
                image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                self.rightView = image
                self.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable var padding = 10

    @IBInspectable var txtpadding = 0


    override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(padding)
        return rect
    }

    override func rightViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.rightViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x - CGFloat(padding)
        return rect
    }

    override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.placeholderRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(txtpadding)

        return rect
    }

    override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(txtpadding)
        return rect
    }
    override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        var rect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
        rect.origin.x = rect.origin.x + CGFloat(txtpadding)
        return rect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
var imageView = UIImageView()
// Set Image on text Field
    func imageOnTextField(textField : UITextField, imageName : String)
    {
        textField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight))
        let image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        imageView.image = image
        textField.rightView = imageView
        imageView.image = imageView.image!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

    }
```