# UITextField with UIButton inside. User should be able to type letters but cursor should stop when it reaches the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

[image]

I have in a project the above UITextField with a button inside. When user is typing the cursor should move but when it reaches the UIButton should stop. Actually the width of the editable area of the UITextField should be until the user reaches the start of the dark blue UIButton image. Text written should not go beyond the UIButton but the user should be able to continue writing.

Is this somehow possible? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Set the `rightView` property of the `UITextField`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Could you please explain with a small example sir?

Comment: `UIButton *myButon = [...]; [myTextview setRightView: myButton]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a button on right view of UItextfield in such way that, text should not overlap the button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082339/add-a-button-on-right-view-of-uitextfield-in-such-way-that-text-should-not-over)

Comment: Let me check sir

Comment: No this does not solve the issue because the button is already in the uitextfield using constraints

Comment: And could you set it as `rightView` instead? Or you could put a transparent rightView that will make placeholder for your button. Or you can override I guess `textRectForBounds:` or `editingRectForBounds:` to make the text area not contains the button...

Comment: Let me try it sir, i do not know how to do it i will search for override textRectForBounds

Comment: I did this sir     UIView *rightView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.searchBarIconView.frame.size.width+22, self.searchBarTextField.frame.size.height)];
    rihtView.backgroundColor = self.searchBarTextField.backgroundColor;
    self.searchBarTextField.rightView = rightView;
    self.searchBarTextField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways; but i had to use also  self.searchBarTextField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(10, 0, 0); to move cursor a bit to the right because it didnt show correctly on the left side...